# What is "DescriptionElement" must not be in the WSDL 2.0 namespace"?

Tags: xsd, wsdl2java, wsdl-2.0

I have this error when I try to convert WSDL and XSD to Java in Netbeans.

> SEVERE: Woden[Error],0:0,WSDL520,Extension element
>   "{http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl}type" in the context of
>   "org.apache.woden.wsdl20.xml.DescriptionElement" must not be in the
>   WSDL 2.0 namespace. mar 16, 2017 12:43:12 EM
>   org.apache.woden.internal.ErrorHandlerImpl warning

The description part for every file is below:

**WSDL file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<description
    targetNamespace="http://www.spads.lfv.se/2017/service/afip"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.spads.lfv.se/2017/service/wsdl/publisher"
    xmlns:wsoap="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/soap"
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:wsdlx="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl-extensions"
    xmlns:inboundOutboundFlight="http://www.spads.lfv.se/2017/service/flightElements"
    xmlns:FID="http://www.spads.lfv.se/2017/service/FlightID">
```

**XSD File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.spads.lfv.se/2017/service/flightElements"
           xmlns:inboundOutboundFlight = "http://www.spads.lfv.se/2017/service/flightElements">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link between XSD and WSDL should be proper established. Therefore, the description part needs to be changed and assured. Altova software is really helpful to generate a simple WSDL file that can be used for creating other operations.

[Altova software](https://www.altova.com/download-trial.html)

Also, the description should be in the syntax below:

**WSDL file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:description
    targetNamespace="http://new.webservice.namespace"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl"
    xmlns:wsoap="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/soap"
    xmlns:whttp="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/http"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tns="http://new.webservice.namespace"
    xmlns:inboundOutboundFlight="http://www.spads.lfv.se/2017/service/flightElements"
    xmlns:wsdlx="http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl-extensions">
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.spads.lfv.se/2017/service/flightElements" schemaLocation="AirportFlightInformationElements.xsd"/>
</wsdl:types>
```

**XSD File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.spads.lfv.se/2017/service/flightElements">
```